# List LDAP module in Apache (PHP -m)

Tags: php, ldap, cpanel

Question.

LDAP is installed easyapache module and test its operation:

```
# /Usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -l
# /Usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -M
```

But when checking with "PHP -m" does not appear

-m Show compiled in modules so.

http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.options.php

The installation process is performed with: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Apache+Module%3A+LDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an LDAP-Module for apache (mod_authnzldap IIRC). It can be used to do HTTP-Authentication against the LDAP from the apache-httpd-webserver. That one is configured in the apache-config-files like `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`. Have a look at the appropriate website https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html.

And then there's the LDAP-Module for PHP (ext/ldap). It can be used to interact with LDAP-Servers from PHP-Scripts. That's the module you need when you want to use the PHP-functions described at http://php.net/ldap. Using `php -m` will only show `ext/ldap` but not `mod_authnzldap`

So depending on what you want to do you might need to reinstall the PHP-module as described in php.net/manual/ldap.installation.php

I hope that helps a bit.